# Screen recorder which is compatible with Skype

Tags: skype, desktop-recording

I have SimpleScreenRecorder, but it doesn't record Skype (like fraps or other screen recorders do).

Can you recommend any screen recorders which record Skype?

Comment: Why doesn't it record Skype? Are you getting an error, black video?

Comment: Nope,but it doesn't.

Comment: Does it record other applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) to record your screen.

It can record your whole screen or a specific area of your screen (your desktop and games).

The application claims to be very fast, even on slow computers. It also claims to use very few resources.

You can install it by executing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

And if you want to record 32-bit games on a 64-bit Ubuntu, also execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I read you were using a screenrecorder, not SimpleScreenRecorder.